Typescript error when accessing 2 different values dynamically inside the same object
I'm building a component library and I'm stuck on this typescript error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'levelTypes | semanticTypes' can't be used to index type '{ level1: { highEmphasis: string; mediumEmphasis: string; outlineHighEmphasis: string; outlineMediumEmphasis: string; semantic: { info: string; onInfo: string; negative: string; onNegative: string; ... 12 more ...; AIGradientEndpoint: string; }; interactive: { ...; }; }; ... 15 more ...; aiIntense: { ...; }; } | { ....'.

  Property 'level1' does not exist on type '{ level1: { highEmphasis: string; mediumEmphasis: string; outlineHighEmphasis: string; outlineMediumEmphasis: string; semantic: { info: string; onInfo: string; negative: string; onNegative: string; ... 12 more ...; AIGradientEndpoint: string; }; interactive: { ...; }; }; ... 15 more ...; aiIntense: { ...; }; } | { ....'.ts(7053)

When I dynamically access 2 different keys inside my color palette object:
theme.fdsTheme.palette[getForeground(level)][level].interactive.highEmphasisSurface

This is my component code:
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

type levelTypes =
  | "level1"
  | "level2"
  | "level3"
  | "level4"
  | "level5"
  | "level6"
  | "level7";

type semanticTypes =
  | "negative"
  | "negativeIntense"
  | "critical"
  | "criticalIntense"
  | "positive"
  | "positiveIntense"
  | "info"
  | "infoIntense"
  | "attention"
  | "attentionIntense"
  | "ai"
  | "aiIntense";


interface ButtonStyleProps {
  level: levelTypes | semanticTypes;
}


const isNavigation = (level: levelTypes | semanticTypes): boolean => {
  return level === "level6" || level === "level7";
};

const getForeground = (level: levelTypes | semanticTypes)=> {
  if (isNavigation(level)) {
    return "onNavigation";
  } else {
    return "onSurface";
  }
};

const StyledButton = styled(BaseButton)<ButtonStyleProps>(({ theme, level }) => {

  return {
    [`&.${buttonClasses.root}`]: {
      // various styles...

      "&.fds-Button-primary": {
        backgroundColor:
          theme.fdsTheme.palette[getForeground(level)][level].interactive.highEmphasisSurface,
        color:
          theme.fdsTheme.palette[getForeground(level)][level].interactive.onHighEmphasis,
        border: `0px solid ${
          theme.fdsTheme.palette[getForeground(level)][level].interactive.highEmphasisOutline
        }`,
      },
    },
  };
});

I haven't found anything on this specific problem when trying to access 2 keys dynamically. The only solutions I'm finding is to use index types but those examples always only consist of accessing one single key dynamically. Here is what I tried:
// Define my theme as its own type
import "@emotion/react";
import { Theme } from "../theme";

type DefaultTheme = typeof Theme;

declare module "@emotion/react" {
  export interface Theme extends DefaultTheme {}
}


import { Theme } from "@emotion/react";


// previous code ...


const StyledButton = styled(BaseButton)<ButtonStyleProps>(({ theme, level }) => {

  return {
    [`&.${buttonClasses.root}`]: {
      // various styles...

      "&.fds-Button-primary": {
        backgroundColor:
          theme.fdsTheme.palette[getForeground(level) as keyof Theme][level as keyof Theme].interactive.highEmphasisSurface,
      },
    },
  };
});

EDIT:
Here's some dummy code for simplification:
interface TestProps {
  levelOne: "color" | "typo";
  levelTwo: "level1" | "level2" | "level3";
}

function TestComponent({ levelOne, levelTwo }: TestProps) {
  const theme = {
    color: {
      level1: {
        color: "",
      },
      level2: {
        color: "",
      },
    },
    typo: {
      level1: {
        color: "",
      },
      level2: {
        color: "",
      },
      level3: {
        color: "",
      },
    },
  };

  const checkLevel = (
    level: "level1" | "level2" | "level3",
  ): "color" | "typo" => {
    return level === "level1" || level === "level2" ? "color" : "typo";
  };

  const c = theme[checkLevel(levelTwo)][levelTwo].color;

  console.log(c);
}

The error would be at
theme[checkLevel(levelTwo)][levelTwo].color;


You pretty much need generics here. Does this approach meet your needs?  If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I moved this out of the component:
type Color = "color" | "typo";
type Level = "level1" | "level2" | "level3";

const theme = {
  color: {
    level1: {
      color: "",
    },
    level2: {
      color: "",
    },
  },
  typo: {
    level1: {
      color: "",
    },
    level2: {
      color: "",
    },
    level3: {
      color: "",
    },
  },
};

Then wrote this:
type Theme = typeof theme;
type Themes = keyof Theme;

type KeyMap<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: keyof T[P];
} 

type InvertResult<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P]]: P
}

type LevelToTheme = InvertResult<KeyMap<Theme>>;
type GetThemes<L extends Level> = LevelToTheme[L];

type SelectOne<
  Options extends Themes,
  PriorityTheme extends Themes
> = PriorityTheme extends Extract<Options, PriorityTheme> ?
  PriorityTheme : Exclude<Options, PriorityTheme>;

type PriorityTheme = "color";

const checkLevel = <L extends Level, TReturn = SelectOne<GetThemes<L>, PriorityTheme>>(
  level: L,
): TReturn => {
  const theme: any = level === "level1" || level === "level2" ? "color" : "typo";
  return theme;
};

The above can infer everything but you will still have a problem:
interface TestProps {
  currentLevelName: Level;
}

function TestComponent({ currentLevelName }: TestProps) {
  // myTheme is Theme['color'] becuse PriorityTheme = "color"
  const myTheme = theme[checkLevel(currentLevelName)]; 
  // ERROR Property 'level3' does not exist on type Theme['color']
  const c = myTheme[currentLevelName].color; 
  console.log(c);
}

This is because currentLevelName: Level; in the component props is not concrete enough. Not sure if it is an option for you, but it would work if you could know the level passed to each component at compile-time:
interface Test2Props {
  currentLevelName: "level2";
}

function Test2Component({ currentLevelName }: Test2Props) {
  // myTheme is Theme['color'] becuse it is infered
  const myTheme = theme[checkLevel(currentLevelName)]; 
  // OK Everythinng is infered as expected
  const c = myTheme[currentLevelName].color; 
  console.log(c);
}

interface Test3Props {
  currentLevelName: "level3";
}

function Test3Component({ currentLevelName }: Test3Props) {
  // myTheme is Theme['typo'] becuse it is infered
  const myTheme = theme[checkLevel(currentLevelName)];
  // OK Everythinng is infered as expected
  const c = myTheme[currentLevelName].color; 
  console.log(c);
}

See it in the playground
If this is not an option, I would leave it the way you have it and do a runtime check and manual casting at:
theme[checkLevel(levelTwo)][levelTwo].color;

